# how to properly rescue this statement in ruby?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rubocop

I have a chef resource and I just added linting with cookstyle to the cookbook. I have this line in the cookbook:

```
existing_value = key.to_s.split('.').inject(node.elasticsearch) { |result, attr| result[attr] } rescue nil if existing_value.nil?
```

It's causing the linter to error. I tried a couple of things, but I'm not sure how to say the same thing and pass the lint test.

```
 Style/RescueModifier: Avoid using rescue in its modifier form
```

If I remove the rescue statement entirely, it causes this exception:

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) on line #52:
    ...
    52: <%= print_value 'action.destructive_requires_name' -%>        
    ...
```

Comment: That's a catch-all `rescue` which is really bad in practice. Can you remove the `rescue nil` part and still have it working? If not, what exceptions does it raise?

Comment: What is the value of `key`? Please read "[mcve]" and the linked page. The error is telling us that `result` is nil.

Comment: The value of `key`, line 52 `action.destructive_requires_name` in this example is `nil` which is in the output of the exception that I posted.

Comment: One minor issue, please don't use `chefstyle`, that is for Chef itself. You want to use `cookstyle` which is for cookbooks.

Comment: it's actually cookstyle. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

So we actually have a method for this if you're on a mildly recent Chef version. You can do this instead:

```
existing_value ||= node.read("elasticsearch.#{key}")
```

And we'll take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Although #coderanger's solution is better, the linter wants you to use the long rescue form

```
begin
  existing_value = key.to_s.split('.').inject(node.elasticsearch) { |result, attr| result[attr] } 
rescue 
  nil
end if existing_value.nil?
```

or usually considered better

```
if existing_value.nil?
  begin
    existing_value = key.to_s.split('.').inject(node.elasticsearch) { |result, attr| result[attr] } 
  rescue 
    nil
  end
end
```

I would also change `rescue` to the more specific `rescue Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError`, rescuing all exceptions is probably not what you want (i.e. you wouldn't want to hide a real exception)

Comment: The actual exception is something different, we just wrap all errors coming out of Erb so they get displayed with some special logic.

Comment: There are countless articles explaining why this is a bad thing. For example you shouldn't catch SystemExit or OutOfMemory errors, because there are other reasons those are thrown. You should at least restrict it to subclasses of `StandardError`